# Graded-irreducible ideals are irreducible?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

One knows that graded ideals in polynomial rings over a field are primary iff they are graded-primary. What about the irreducible ideals?

> Let $I$ be a graded ideal in a polynomial ring over a field. Is it true that $I$ is irreducible if and only if it can't be written as an intersection of two graded ideals (properly containing $I$)?

If the answer is positive in this case, then what's going on if change the ring by an arbitrary $\Bbb N$ (or $\Bbb Z$)-graded ring?

Comment: The case of noetherian modules over rings graded by the integers is studied in [this preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07518) by Justin Chen and Youngsu Kim.

Comment: Thank you Fred, I have a quick look their proof. They used the fact $I$ is irreducible iff the index of reducible of $I$ is one. So their proof need Noetheian condition. My proof is also true for $\mathbb{Z}$-graded (I fell it works for $\mathbb{N}^n$-graded also).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof for any graded (not necessary Noetherian) ring based on [this proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215768/is-an-irreducible-ideal-in-r-also-irreducible-in-rx/215864#215864).
For simplify we assume $R = \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} R_n$, although the proof hold for any graded ring.

Firstly, we give some definitions. For any $f = f_0 + \cdots + f_n$ we define
$$\mathrm{begin} (f) = \min\{i \mid f_i \neq 0\},$$
$$\mathrm{end} (f) = \max\{i \mid f_i \neq 0\},$$
$$c(f) = \mathrm{end}(f) - \mathrm{begin}(f).$$
Thus $f$ is a non-zero homogeneous iff $c(f) = 0$.

Assume that $(0)$ is a graded-irreducible ideal of $R$ and prove that it is an irreducible ideal. Assume $(0)$ is the intersection of two non-zero ideals. We can choose two non-zero elements $f$ and $g$ such that $(0) = (f) \cap (g)$. Here we choose $f$ and $g$ such that $c(f) + c(g)$ is **minimal**. Since $(0)$ is graded irreducible we have $c(f) + c(g)>0$. Assume $c(f) \le c(g)$, thus $c(g)>0$ i.e., $g$ is non-homogeneous.
Let $a = \mathrm{begin}(f)$ and $b = \mathrm{begin}(g)$ we have $(f_a) \cap (g_b) \neq 0$. Thus we have two homogeneous elements $d$ and $e$ such that $df_a = eg_b \neq 0$. Replacing $f$ and $g$ by $df$ and $eg$, respectively, we can assume henceforth that $\mathrm{begin}(f) = \mathrm{begin}(g):=b$ and $f_b = g_b$.

Similar to [this proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215768/is-an-irreducible-ideal-in-r-also-irreducible-in-rx/215864#215864) we have

**Claim 1:** Let $r$ be a homogeneous element and $b = \mathrm{begin}(f)$ such that $rf_b = 0$. Then $rf = 0$ and $rg = 0$.

**Claim 2:** Let $h = h_0 + \cdots + h_t$ be an element such that $hf = 0$. Then $h_if = 0$ for all $i = 0, ..., t$.

**Claim 3:** $hf = 0$ iff $hg = 0$.

Let $g' = g-f$ we have $c(g')<c(g)$ since $f_b = g_b$. By the minimality we have $(f) \cap (g-f) \neq 0$. Thus there are $u, v$ and $w$ such that
$$0\neq w = uf = v(g-f).$$
If $vg \neq 0$ then $vg = (u+v)f \in (f) \cap (g)$, a contradiction.

If $vg = 0$, then $vf = 0$ by Claim 3. So $w = 0$. This is also a contradiction.

The proof is complete.

Answer (score 1):

There is a positive answer to this question now by Pham Hung Quy's post here and [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07518), but one can also ask this question about other gradings.  This is not an answer, but a long comment:

- $\mathbb{N}^n$-graded are monomial ideals: It is well-known that monomial irreducible decomposition is irreducible decomposition.
- Ideals finely graded (Hilbert function takes only the value 1) by an affine semigroup (a finitely generated subsemigroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$) are toric ideals.  They are prime and irreducible.
- Ideals graded by some affine semigroup $A$ could be an interesting next goal.  Since the grading is torsion free, there is an $A$-graded primary decomposition, but irreducible decomposition is not clear.

Descending further in the hierarchy of grading monoids, a *commutative Noetherian monoids* is any quotient of $\mathbb{N}^n$ by a congruence.  An ideal is graded by  such a monoid if and only if it is a binomial ideal (Proposition 1.11 in *Binomial Ideals* by Eisenbud and Sturmfels) and the theory of binomial ideals can be developed somewhat similarly to that of monomial ideals.  However, an ideal graded by a fixed commutative Noetherian monoid $Q$ need not even have a primary decomposition into $Q$-graded ideals.  For example, $(x^2-xy, xy-y^2) = (x,y^2) \cap (x-y)$.  The ideal on the left hand side is (finely) $Q$-graded for some monoid $Q$ in which $x$ and $y$ have different degrees, but they must have the same degree in the unique minimal prime $(x-y)$.

Now one could ask if in general binomial ideals have binomial irreducible decompositions, that is, letting $Q$ vary in the decomposition.  This was an open problem in Eisenbud/Sturmfels, but the answer is negative by Section 6 in [*Irreducible decomposition of binomial ideals* by Kahle, Miller, O'Neill](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02607).